# Vector that contains keys to sort a map by values

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary, vector

I have a:

```
std::map<long, std::wstring> fNames;       // ex: fNames[FileReferenceNumber] = L"hello.txt"
```

As `std::map` has keys ordered, **but not values** (a hash-table `unordered_map` has even nothing ordered), I'd like to create a vector:

```
std::vector<long> v;
```

that would contain the keys **to allow an iteration of `fNames` sorted by values**.

Example: if we have

> 9187 => "hello.txt"
>      13   => "z.txt"
>      1777 => "a.txt"

Then `v` would be: `[1777, 9187, 13]`, allowing an iteration of `fNames` sorted by values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) 
    wcout << fNames[v[i]];     // a.txt, hello.txt, z.txt
```

**Is there a way to create this vector `v` by using `std::sort`? I don't see how. Should I use a custom predicate?**

---

PS: Even better: would it be possible to produce a `std::vector<wstring> w`  sorted? i.e. each element `w[0]`, `w[1]`, etc. would contain a "link" (pointer?) to `fNames`'s wstrings, but not a copy (to avoid duplicating the string data)?

Or maybe it would be a `std::vector<wchar_t *> w`?

Comment: Make second `multimap<wstring, long>`, that will store the sorted values plus their keys. Creating and sorting the `vector<wstring>` of values on each change of original `map<long, wstring>` will take too much time.

Comment: @ikleschenkov is it similar to have a map + its "reverse map"? what happens if multiple keys have same value? Let's say `a[1] = "blah"; a[2] = "blah";` What would be the reverse map `reversea["blah"]`? Isn't it possible to have just a vector for the sorting, as detailed in the question?

Comment: `multimap` will handle the duplicated "keys" (which is values from first map). Solution depends on how ofter you need to refresh the vector of sorted values. If you need this rarely, than sorted `vector` is fine. If you need this too often, then it's better have "reversed" `multimap`, because it will be faster, than updating and sorting the vector each time.

Answer (score 1):

Use a vector of pointers to the elements of the map, and sort those pointers. This gives you access to both the longs and the wstrings, without copying.

```
using value_type = std::map<long, std::wstring>::value_type;
std::vector<value_type*> v;
for (auto& e : fNames)
    v.push_back(&e);
auto compare_by_second = [](value_type* lhs, value_type* rhs) {
    return lhs->second < rhs->second;
};
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare_by_second);
```

Now you have access to the `wstring` values through `v[N]->second`, and the long values through `v[N]->first`.

Pre-C++11 version

```
bool compare_by_second(std::pair<const long, std::wstring>* lhs,
                       std::pair<const long, std::wstring>* rhs)
{
    return lhs->second < rhs->second;
}

// in some function
std::map<long, std::wstring> fNames;
...
std::vector<std::pair<const long, std::wstring>*> v;
for (std::map<long, std::wstring>::iterator b = fNames.begin();
     b != fNames.end(); ++b)
{
    v.push_back(&*b);
}
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare_by_second);
```

If you only need the strings, and not the longs, then you can just use a vector of pointers to strings instead.

```
bool deref_compare(std::wstring* lhs, std::wstring* rhs)
{
    return *lhs < *rhs;
}

// in some function
std::map<long, std::wstring> fNames;
...
std::vector<std::wstring*> v;
for (std::map<long, std::wstring>::iterator b = fNames.begin();
     b != fNames.end(); ++b)
{
    v.push_back(&b->second);
}
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), deref_compare);
```

Comment: @Basj: It's `std::pair<const long, std::wstring>`. The `auto&` would be a reference to that type.

Comment: @Basj: Pre c++11 version added.

Comment: Thanks a lot. as I understand it we duplicate the map into a vector of pair, and then we sort this one. Is there a way to do it with just a vector of long ? (and not of pair)

Comment: @Basj: Yes. Just change the `push_back` line to `v.push_back(b->first)`. Are you still wanting to sort by the value of the paired string in that case?

Comment: If so, then I would recommend you first make a vector of pointers to pairs and sort it, like I showed in my answer. Then make a second vector of longs, and just copy over the longs from the pairs in the first vector.

Comment: See previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

> PS: Even better: would it be possible to produce a
>   `std::vector<wstring> w` sorted? i.e. each element `w[0]`, `w[1]`, etc.
>   would contain a "link" (pointer?) to `fNames`'s `wstring`s, but not a copy
>   (to avoid duplicating the string data)?

A `vector<wstring>` would contain duplicates of the strings (as CoW - Copy on Write - has been forbidden for `std::[w]string` since C++11). If you want to use `const wchar_t*` to avoid string duplicates, you can do something like this:

```
vector<const wchar_t*> sortedFilenames;

// Reserve room in the vector, since we know how many strings to add
sortedFilenames.reserve(fNames.size());

// Add string pointers from map to vector
for (const auto& e : fNames) {
    // Avoid duplicates using const wchar_t*
    sortedFilenames.push_back(e.second.c_str());
}

// Sort the string vector
sort(begin(sortedFilenames), end(sortedFilenames), 
    [](const auto& p1, const auto& p2) {
        // Use whatever sorting rule you need here...
        return wcscmp(p1, p2) < 0;
    }
);
```

---

**EDIT** As per your comment, you can use `vector<const wstring*>` as well, e.g.:

```
vector<const wstring*> sortedFilenames;

// Reserve room in the vector, since we know how many strings to add
sortedFilenames.reserve(fNames.size());

// Add string pointers from map to vector
for (const auto& e : fNames) {
    sortedFilenames.push_back(&(e.second));
}

// Sort the string vector
sort(begin(sortedFilenames), end(sortedFilenames),
    [](const auto& p1, const auto& p2) {
        return (*p1) < (*p2); // or whatever sorting rule...
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to do the same and have `vector<wstring *> sortedFilenames` or `vector <const wstring *>`? so I can still have access to the `wstring` structure instead of just a `wchar_t *`(if for example I need to concatenate it with something else when iterating, it would be better to already have a wstring)

Comment: Yes, you can use `vector<const wstring *>` if you want to store _observing_ pointers to the original `wstring`s; I've updated my answer with sample code showing that.

Comment: To get a vector of map's key values, can I use e.first ?

Comment: Yes: `first` --> key, `second` --> value associated to the key.

Answer (score 1):

I will solve this in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), because it is simpler there than [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) or [c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03), and every major compiler vendor has enough support for this to compile:

Make a vector of pointers-to-string and reserve enough space (for efficiency reasons).

```
std::vector<std::wstring const*> sorted_strings;
sorted_strings.reserve(fNames.size());
```

Populate the pointers:

```
for (auto& entry:fNames)
  sorted_strings.push_back( &entry.second );
```

Sort them:

```
std::sort(
  begin(sorted_strings), end(sorted_strings),
  [](auto* lhs, auto* rhs) { return *lhs < *rhs; }
);
```

for a vector of keys:

```
std::vector<int> sorted_keys;
sorted_keys.reserve(fNames.size());
for (auto&& entry:fNames)
  sorted_strings.push_back( entry.first );
std::sort(
  begin(sorted_keys), end(sorted_keys),
  [&](int lhs, int rhs) { return fNames[lhs] < fNames[rhs]; }
);
```

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) you can do away with the `.first` and `.second`:

```
for (auto&[key, value]:fNames)
  sorted_strings.push_back( &value );
```

using structured bindings.

Comment: Thanks a lot. About the "vector of keys" part, what would be the pre c++11 version of `for (auto&& entry:fNames)` ? I was thinking about `for (map<long, wstring>::iterator b = fNames.begin(); b != fNames.end(); ++b)`, is it correct? Also what would the double `&` after `auto` become?

Comment: @basj `auto&&`is a forwarding reference.  There is no equivalent in C++03.  In this case, it means a reference binding to whatever is being iterated over, lifetime extending if required, but not making a copy regardless, mutable if possible but `const` if not.  Above in another range-for I did `auto&` because we where persisting a pointer to a member within the loop, thus we had to guarantee we where iterating over non-temporary data.  And `auto&` won't bind to a temporary.  This is just writing code as generic as is safe as a matter of policy.